# Deletar banco de dados ao desinstalar app

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin-forms

No meu app eu crio o banco de dados feito em SQLite na pasta:

> System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal

Porém em alguns dispositivos(Android) ao desinstalar o app parece que o banco continua na pasta, pois ao instalar o app novamente ele inicia logado e com os dados anteriormente salvos.

Alguém saberia dizer porque isso ocorre e como poderia resolver esse problema?

Comment: Cara, eu percebi isso também somente em um aparelho Asus com Android 7. Parece ser uma modificação do SO feito pelo fabricante. Particularmente achei muito ruim. Significa que ele está mantendo lixo de outros após que desisntalo. Uma alternativa pode ser configurar um _broadcast receiver_ para o evento de desinstalação (precisa confirmar se tem esse, não lembro) e fazer a exclusão manual do banco

Comment: Pois é, mas acho que isso ta acontecendo em um Android 6.0 que uns dos donos da empresa pra onde to fazendo app faz teste. Sugeriam eu fazer isso android:allowBackup="false"  no arquivo AndroidManifest.xml. Só que ainda não testei.

Comment: Já percebi isso também, pelo o que eu tinha notado isso acontece quando você tem mais de um usuário cadastrado no celular (usuário convidado)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partir do Android `Marshmallow` existe uma feature nova, onde dentro do `<application>` você deve setar um valor para o atributo `android:allowBackup`.

No seu caso: `android:allowBackup = false`

Source: [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element)

> Seja para permitir que o aplicativo participe da infraestrutura de backup e restauração. Se esse atributo for definido como false, nenhum backup ou restauração do aplicativo nunca será executado, mesmo por um backup completo do sistema que faria com que todos os dados do aplicativo fossem salvos via adb. O valor padrão deste atributo é true.

Comment: Bom, fiz essas modificações. Agora é aguardar os teste. Obrigado.